# Install of wifi adapter tp-link TL-WN821N on Ubuntu Server LTS 16.04

Tags: server, wireless, tp-link

I have purchased a Wi-Fi adapter for my Ubuntu server and I cannot set up the driver. I thought it would be Plug&Play, but I have this problem now.

*Can anyone help me?*

Comment: Hi vasileios and welcome to askbuntu! Please add the output of the following command to your post: `hwinfo --netcard`

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @abu_bua Could you please review my [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1052995/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your own edits in the future... **;-)**